# extending Java's Linked List for personal use

Tags: java, list, linked-list, adt, extend

So I need a linked list to store multiple variables, so I want to use my hand-made Linked List ADT, but also want Java's Linked List's Comparator Sort from collections.sort();

So I tried and edited my code as following:

```
public class HLinkedList <HTreeNode>  extends LinkedList <HTreeNode>
{

public class HTreeNode {


    public HTreeNode left;
    public HTreeNode right;
    public HTreeNode next;
    public int frequency;
    public char value;
    public String code;
    public HTreeNode(int freq, char val, HTreeNode l, HTreeNode r, HTreeNode n, String code) // code is the path taken to this node, how to explain it in code?
    {
        value = val;
        frequency = freq;
        left = l;
        right = r;
        next = n;
        code = ""; // just initialized ,but have to think through logic.
    }
}
```

but if I do this, instead of just `public class HLinkedList` (which is fine except I can't use  `Collections.sort(HList, comparatorA)`, one line of code that I need to have Java's Linked List for.

anyways, if I have my code as shown above it returns a

```
cannot make static reference to non-static type HTreeNode in following line,
```

with red lining under HTreeNode. This does not happen if I do not try to extend LinkedList.

```
public static void insertIntoPosition(HTreeNode node, int position)
```

also following the above error is an error in

```java
public HLinkedList() //constructor
{
    head = null; //inital value
    nItem = 0;//counter

}
```

where multiple occurences in the code indicate they cannot static reference a non-static head. Usually when stuff like this comes up I click "make that head static", but in this case when I do that even more errors pop up, now pointing to ALL the "head" references.

I would just like to know what is going on when I am trying and failing at extending LinkedList, or if I'm supposed to not extend but do something else maybe?

Comment: This does not look like a list to me. It actually reminds me of a tree.

Comment: yeah it's a list that will be used to make a tree so I tried to put everything in, although i don't think that matters- the professor seemed ok with this

Comment: You're extending LinkedList, which has a member called Head. If I were you, I'd make my own linked list and implement the interface of iComparator. This is a matter of knowing how to use Generics. I'm not heavy into Java, but I remember that much. Good luck with your algorithm structures

Comment: If I were your professor, I would not be OK with this. A tree is not a list.

Comment: if you want to use sort you can also try implementing the List interface.  Collections.sort works with any List implementation that implements Comparable as well.

Comment: What you're trying to do will mess up badly if you try extending `java.util.LinkedList`, and there's no need to extend `LinkedList` to get the benefits of `Collections.sort()`.  What you ought to do is extend `java.util.AbstractSequentialList`, which is a skeletal design for linked-list-style classes.

Comment: great, I didn't realize that was the case

Comment: I think I'll have to go with extending the ABsSeqList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method is a *class method*:

```
 public static void insertIntoPosition(HTreeNode node, int position)
```

Thus it does not need an instance of `HLinkedList` in order to be invoked.

However, your class `HTreeNode` is an *inner class* - and need an "attahced" instance of `HLinkedList` in order to be instantiated.

These two facts contradict each other (you cannot instantiate an object of this type in this method)

You can add the `static` keyword to the declaration of `HTreeNode` in order to overcome this:

```
public static class HTreeNode { //note the static keyword usage
    ....
}
```

Comment: ah so if I have to make my whole HTreeNode a static

Answer (score 2):

Another problem is that you should not have a generic type qualifier on `HLinkedList`. It's not doing what you think it is. What you are specifying is to create a class that stores "something", and this isn't the inner class. Instead, you need to move the `HTreeNode` class outside `HLinkedList` and then use this instead:

```
public class HLinkedList extends LinkedList <HTreeNode>
```

Otherwise, the generic type hides the inner class and I can also create a `HLinkedList` that stores strings.

```
HLinkedList<String> hll = new HLinkedList<String>();
hll.add("Hello World");
```